# Getting an error while "update-database" command is running: There is already an object named '...' in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-core-2.1

I have a few EF Core models:

```
abstract class Weapon {
   public int    Id   { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Axe : Weapon {
}

class Sword : Weapon {
}

class GameDbContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Weapon>   Weapons   { get; set; }

    public GameDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options){
        this.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

         this.SetModelsConfigurations(modelBuilder);

         modelBuilder.Entity<Axe>  ().HasBaseType<Weapon>();
         modelBuilder.Entity<Sword>().HasBaseType<Weapon>();
    }
}
```

When I run "add-migration" command everything is Ok. But when I run "update-database" command, I get an error:

> There is already an object named 'Weapons' in the database.

This DB wasn't created. Why do I get this error? Please explain to me how DB models should be configured.

Comment: Only use Migrate or MigrateAsync. This will already create a database. The CreateDatabase command itself will create a database according to it's current model, disregarding your migration logic.

Comment: @Silvermind Is that a command? Or Method?

Comment: @Silvermind ( I see that problem was with method:  this.Database.EnsureCreated(). "update-databes" command was done after this method was deleted.

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought you were using migrations in code. If you're using the cli, you should just be able to use update-database according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/)

Comment: Ah, thats why I mixed them up. Yeah I meant EnsureCreated instead of CreateDatabase. Don't use that command with migrations. ;)